# Facebook photo gallery viewer

Tags: javascript, facebook

It's there a specific way to use the same gallery viewer inside an facebook app as facebook uses to display photos ( http://phill.co/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/new-facebook-lightbox.jpg )? 
I guess that using it isn't part of facebook api.

Or is there any known jQuery plugin that has the same look and feel ?

Thanks,
Victor

Comment: There are many good lightbox-type jQuery plugins that does that. It's all about CSS to make it feel the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you **can't** use Facebook website-specific features in your app. Including the photo viewer.

Same thing applies on the overlay effect itself! You can't have your lightbox that is in your Facebook Page Tab or Canvas overlays outside the iframes created for your app.

Now creating a Facebook-like photo viewer is a matter of design. I've wrote a [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-photo-albums-browser-using-facebook-graph-api/77/) a while back about *creating* a Facebook album viewer with a demo. It may give you a head start.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Funny thing it's that i've used your code a while ago when i've started with Facebook api(php sdk). Thanks for that also.